# In NODE js - accessing variable from one file in another file without html

Tags: node.js, var, frisby.js

I have one `var URL = 'http://something';` in `test.js`
I want to access to this var in another `main.js` file and for ex. have `var MEU =URL+ '/sss'`;. How can I do that?

I want to export this var URL from some file in my main file, but still give me it is not declared message. Please help me with full path example, or something like "export" (which I can't use because it is reserved word)

Don't use HTML.

Answer (score 1):

after your EDIT :
If you store your variable in the global scope, your variable should be accessible form anywhere then.

in your first file :

```
var URL = 'something';
```

in your main file

```
console.log(URL);
```

You just have to make sure your the file where you declare URL is before your main file. Then you can just access it normally as it is in the global scope.

Comment: The first part of your answer is as correct as the question allows. The second part, though, missed out that they've said they're **not** doing this in "html" (by which I assume they mean in a web browser, the question is really unclear but it's true that in nearly all JavaScript environments, there's one global environment).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make sure of two things.

1. Declare the variable outside a function ie Declare var URL = 'something'; at the top of the js file.
2. Make sure this file is loaded before the next js file in which you use it.

You can also declare like this in html file for better readability

```
<script type='text/javascript' > 
  var URL = 'something'; 
</script>
```

Comment: I want to export this var URL from some file in my main file, but still give me it is not declared message. Please help me with full path example, or something like "export" (which I can't use because it is reserved word)

Answer (score 0):

What is your working environment? Is java/jsp + html? Or, is it Node.js?
If you can use html, Raj's solution should work.

If you are using node , this [link](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/) might help you.

And, if nothing works for you, probably you need to store it in db, and fetch it from there (may be not precisely what you need here to get your work done).

Comment: OK. So, looks like it a framework based on Node. So, the link in the post may help.

Answer (score 0):

For two Node.js files, you need to export the variable in the file where it is declared to expose it to the outside world and you need to require it in the file where you want to use it in.

Where it's declared in test.js and exported:

```
var URL = 'http://something';
exports.URL = URL;
```

Now for the usage in main.js:

```
var URL = require('/home/username/test.js').URL;
var MEU = URL+ '/sss';
```

Replace /home/username/test.js with the correct path on your system.

Here is a pretty good treatment of the topic:
http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/